# I'm using a MUI Stepper for my forms but the some of fields get the value when press next

Tags: database, forms, stepper

So im using and developing a form with the progress type of forms so the only problem here is the Barangay Fields and the Guardians Relationship

So this what it looks like

[image: Family Progress Part]

[image: This is the barangay part im saying]

The problem here is not the barangay but the Guardian Relation the value of the barangay is being get by the guardian relationship so when i proceed to the family information it gets the data of the barangay how to stop this below are my code

Barangay Field

```
<MUI.Grid id="barangayGrid">
              <MUI.InputLabel htmlFor="barangay_name" id="barangayLabel">
                Barangay
              </MUI.InputLabel>
              <Controller
                name="barangay_name"
                control={control}
                defaultValue={scholarProfiles.barangay_name || ''}
                rules={{
                  required: selectedRegionCode === '130000000' ? false : 'Barangay is required',
                  validate: (value) => (selectedRegionCode === '130000000' || value !== '') || 'Please select a barangay',
                }}
                render={({ field }) => (
                  <MUI.FormControl sx={{ width: '100%', borderRadius: '8px' }}>
                    <MUI.Select
                      id="barangay_name"
                      native
                      {...field}
                    >
                      <option value="">Select Barangay</option>
                      {barangays.map((barangay) => (
                        <option key={barangay.name} value={barangay.name}>
                          {barangay.name}
                        </option>
                      ))}
                    </MUI.Select>
                  </MUI.FormControl>
                )}
              />
              {errors.barangay_name && (
                <p id="errMsg">
                  <MUI.InfoIcon className="infoErr" />
                  {errors.barangay_name?.message}
                </p>
              )}
            </MUI.Grid>
```

Guardian Relation Field

```
  <MUI.Grid id="relationToScholarGrid">
              <MUI.InputLabel htmlFor="relation_to_scholar" id="relationToScholarLabel">Guarduan Relation</MUI.InputLabel>
              <Controller
                name='relation_to_scholar'
                control={control}
                defaultValue={scholarFamMembers.relation_to_scholar || ""}
                rules={{
                  required: 'Relation to scholar is required',
                  validate: (value) => value !== '' || 'Please select a relation to scholar'
                }}
                render={({ field }) => (
                  <MUI.FormControl sx={{ width: '100%', borderRadius: '8px' }}>
                    <MUI.Select
                      id="relation_to_scholar"
                      native
                      {...field}                    >
                      <option value="" disabled>Select Relation</option>
                      <option value="Father">Father</option>
                      <option value="Mother">Mother</option>
                      <option value="Guardian">Guardian</option>
                    </MUI.Select>
                  </MUI.FormControl>
                )}
              />
              {errors.relation_to_scholar && (
                  <p id='errMsg'>
                      <MUI.InfoIcon className='infoErr' />
                      {errors.relation_to_scholar?.message}
                  </p>
              )}
            </MUI.Grid>
```

I can provide other part of my code for you to have nowledge about it more

Comment: can u share codesandbox link?

Comment: Ohhh for now i can only give code but im willing to provide code for every part that causing problems for this